# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't display locators for my webElements with mouse move, how it does Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

[image: IntelliJ]

[image: Eclipse]

I am using Cucumber framework with POM(Java/Selenium/jUnit)) and @FindBy annotation in my page elements classes:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Email Doc')]") public List <WebElement> emailDocuments;
```

by using:

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

Recently I decided to install IntelliJ and start working in this beautiful environment, I really enjoy it. but unfortunately, I noticed when I move the mouse cursor on the web element - I can't see the locator of the element as it was in Eclipse. I attached 2 screenshots, hope it will make more sense for you, and hope it is possible to fix it somehow in the settings or with the help of some plugins. (Please don't suggest to avid using @FindBy annotation, it will require a lot of changes in my framework). Thank you so much in advance for any help!

UPDATE: I just noticed this is not only about web elements, also all the methods that I implement in different classes, I can't see the structure/implementation of those methods when I move the mouse, but it works in Eclipse for me.

I tried to do research and didn't find anything except the check box in the settings for "Show on mouse move".

Comment: You may want to try a Selenium plugin for IntelliJ. I can see at least two different options in the Marketplace. (as an aside: I only saw this because someone added the Java tag. Make sure to add a relevant language tag whenever possible, so the right people will see your question)

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Jorn! I added all tags here since I use Java/SE and I changed my coding work environment from Eclipse to IntelliJ. Seems to me that all the tags are correct here and relevant to my question. Regarding your suggestion: how Selenium plugin will help here? I can't see in the pop-up window the implementation of my own methods or the locator for the web element when point the mouse cursor in those. But this feature works perfectly in Eclipse w/o any additional plugins.