# Howto prevent Eclipse "Initializing search indices" all the time?

Tags: eclipse, maven, indexing

I have a big multimodule Eclipse project with more than 20 projects in it.

The problem is that quite often after pulling from git repository and searching for a type/resource (CTRL+SHIFT+T/R) in a popup that opens Eclipse starts **Initializing search indices**. This takes quite long and is very disturbing when you need to use git operations frequently.

This did not happen earlier (worked with this project structure for 2 years). I cannot tell in which version it started to behave like this but my current version is:

*Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

2023-03 (4.27.0)*.

Comment: @Jorn Just another fanboy comment from you. Do you really think people use an IDE because they don't know there are other IDEs? Get over the fact that others are more productive without your favorite product you pay money for.

Comment: Does this also happen in the current version of Eclipse instead of the 2023-03 which is two releases behind? Also, make sure EGit is up to date, as quite older versions trigger a full refresh on actions such as switching branches.

Comment: @howlger Going to upgrade and se if the problem still persists. Just that this version has worked nice this far.

Comment: @howlger Meanin that I have not made any distribution upgrades as the version shows but maybe some plugins are updated or so.

Comment: @Jorn perhaps your enthusiasm could be directed toward unanswered questions about IntelliJ, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77289255/intellij-idea-doesnt-display-locators-for-my-webelements-with-mouse-move-how-i.

Comment: Initializing search indices all the time is not normal and 20 or 30 projects is not much. Something seems to cause a full refresh. It might be a plugin you installed. So please try a fresh installation without additional plugins. If you can reproduce it, close some of the projects to narrow down the cause further.